# PDFDocument dataRepresentation is slow... How to show progress?

Tags: performance, macos, cocoa, pdf, pdfkit

I'm currently working on a Cocoa application that works with PDFs, and am using Apple's PDFKit to do the work. Saving the PDF is proving a problem, as I'd like to show a progress bar while that's happening, which doesn't seem to be possible using the standard `writeToURL:` method. So, I went and used Grand Central Dispatch instead.

The problem with this is that the `dataRepresentation` method used to get the NSData to write is terribly slow in converting any PDF larger than ~3MB to NSData, and so the progress bar stalls for a few seconds while my program is waiting for the data, which seems to make the users think the program has stalled completely. And I don't really want them thinking that.

My question is, is there anything I can do to either speed up the `dataRepresentation` method, or report its progress to the user?

Here's the Grand Central Dispatch code I ended up writing:

```
NSData *pdf = [doc dataRepresentation]; // R-e-a-l-l-y S-l-o-w

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_data_t dat = dispatch_data_create([pdf bytes], [pdf length], queue, DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT);

__block dispatch_io_t channel =
dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM,
                             [path UTF8String],     // Convert to C-string
                             O_WRONLY,              // Open for writing
                             0,                     // No extra flags
                             queue,
                             ^(int error){
                                 // Cleanup code for normal channel operation.
                                 // Assumes that dispatch_io_close was called elsewhere.
                                 if (error == 0) {
                                     dispatch_release(channel);
                                     channel = NULL;
                                 }
                             });
// The next two lines make sure that the block in dispatch_io_write
// gets called about 60 times, so that it can update the progress bar.
dispatch_io_set_low_water(channel,[pdf length]/60);
dispatch_io_set_high_water(channel,[pdf length]/60);

dispatch_io_write(channel,
                  0,
                  dat,
                  queue,
                  ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
                      if (data) {
                          // Increment progress bar
                      }
                      if (error) {
                          // Handle errors
                      }
                      if (done) {
                          dispatch_io_close(channel, NULL);
                      }
                  });
dispatch_release(dat);
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`PDFDocumentDidBeginPageWriteNotification` and `PDFDocumentDidEndPageWriteNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) notifications, which are sent during `-writeToURL:`. The notifications tell you what page is processing, which you can compare to the total number of pages in the document to show progress.

Comment: Should have thought of looking for a notification... Thanks!